# Printing diamond of stars

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, while-loop

I am printing diamond of stars but my code is compiling and running but it is only printing the half of diamond......anyone please help.

below I have mentioned my code.
I cannot understand the problem as why the system is only executing the first half and not the other half of diamond.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n,i=0,j;
    cin>>n;

    while(i<=(n/2))
    {
    j=0;
    while(j<(n/2)-i){
        cout<<" ";
        j=j+1;

    }
    j=0;
    while(j<i+1){
        cout<<"*";
        j=j+1;
    }
    j=0;
    while(j<=i-1){
        cout<<"*";
        j=j+1;
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    i=i+1;
    }

while(i<=(n/2))

      {
        j=0;
        while(j<(n/2)-i)
        {
            cout<<" ";
            j=j+1;

        }
        j=0;
        while(j<i)
            {
            cout<<"*";
            j=j+1;
            }
        j=0;
        while(j<i-1){
            cout<<"*";
            j++;
        }
        cout<<"\n";
        i--;
      }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Have you tried reading your code and following along on a piece of paper or a notepad?

Comment: please show the output.

Comment: You need another loop condition for the second part.

Comment: By the way this is ***NOT C***

Comment: 2nd `while(i<=(n/2))` is wrong.

Comment: @Thomas no, not C. In C, there is nothing called `using namespace std;`

Comment: yes I have tried reading my code on paper it works fine..@Eregrith

Comment: I have also checked that condition by resetting i but it still does not work@Pratyush Khare

Comment: @SouravGhosh well spotted :)

Comment: @PrayasJain I think you missed something (or misinterpreted it) because it does not, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int main() {

int n;

 cin>>n;

    for(int i=0;i<=n/2;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if((i+j==n/2) ||(abs(i-j)==n/2))
                printf("*");
            else
                printf(" ");
        }
         printf("\n");
    }
 for(int i=n/2-1;i>=0;i--)
 {
     for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
     {
         if((i+j==n/2) || (abs(i-j)==n/2))
             printf("*");
         else
             printf(" ");
     }
     printf("\n");
 }


return 0;
}
```

it have worked example if n=5

```
   *

 *   *

*     *

 *   *

   *
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same iterator (i) in both while() loops. Either use a different iterator in the second loop, or reset it.

Comment: The idea is to increment `i` in the first loop, then decrement it in the second, I guess, so resetting won't work.

Answer (score 0):

When you first loop in `i` ends, you have `i = n/2 + 1`
In the second loop you want `i` to decrease. So it must be `while (i > 0)` and not what it currently is.

Comment: thanks for the help but it still does not work if I assign     i<=n/2+1 in second loop

Comment: so what should I do to execute that section..@Sinstein

Comment: @PrayasJain edited the answer. You should change the condition of your second loop.

Comment: I have changed the condition and assigned i<=n/2 + 1 but it still not works

Comment: @PrayasJain Do you mean `i = n/2 + 1` and set condition to `i > 0` because what you mention is not an assignment but a condition

Comment: yes I mean `i<=n/2+1` , and if I change `i>0` then the code works but the number of rows are increased by 1 in the diamond.@Sinstein

Comment: Then just do not reset `i`. Do NOT set `i = n/2 + 1` after the first loop. Just change the condition and check the output.

Comment: @PrayasJain And if that causes an extra line to appear in the middle. Then you should decrement `i` before entering the second loop. So to finalise: 
1. Change loop condition
2. Do `i--` at the end of the loop

Comment: can you please tell me the exact condition to be entered@Sinstein

Comment: @PrayasJain You should set your second loop as ` i--;    while( i > 0 ) { } `